# SwiftUI: View as property

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to have a `View` property?

```
struct MyObj {
    var myView: View
}
```

When I try this I get a compiler error of: `Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want a property that can hold any kind of `View`, you have a couple of choices.

If it'll always be the same type of view at runtime, you can make the container generic. This is what all of SwiftUI's built-in container views (like `VStack`) do. Declare your type this:

```
struct MyObject<Content: View> {
    var myView: Content
}
```

If you want it to hold different types of view at runtime, you need to use `AnyView`:

```
struct MyObject {
    var myView: AnyView
}
```

And you'll need to manually wrap your view instances in `AnyView` when assigned to the property.